# how to secure React Single Page App/Creat React App

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, csrf

I am building an e-commerce website using React Single Page App/Creat React App  and in my backend iam using Express.js.

because every request to the server uses the API, is that very dangerous?
because everyone can access our API right?

**so how do you deal with this?**

should i use CSRF?

I've searched for ways in a few **days** with this CSRF and the results remain the same, **it doesn't work!**

I have tried it using CSURF Express, and I get a lot of bugs. most people talk by sending it through CSRF tokens to client. I tried it and when the first page opened sometimes i got an error `Invalid CSRF token`

**Server.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import passport from 'passport';
import connection from './config/conn';
import { 
    CategoryRoutes,
    ProductRoutes,
    CartRoutes,
    AuthRoutes,
    TrackRoutes,
    AddressRoutes,
    ShippingRoutes,
    UIRoutes,
    LookbookRoutes,
    CheckoutRoutes
} from './modules';
import session  from 'express-session';
import csrf  from 'csurf'
import cors from 'cors'
import cookieParser  from 'cookie-parser'
// import cookieSession from 'cookie-session'
import passportSetup from './config/passport-setup';
import keys from './config/keys';
import uuidv4  from 'uuid/v4';
import UAparser  from 'ua-parser-js';
import { ensureSession } from './config/sessionCheck';
// import path from 'path';
const app = express();

app.use(session({
    genid: function (req) {
        return uuidv4() // use UUIDs for session IDs
    },
    name:keys.session.name,
    secret: keys.session.secret,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    rolling:true,
    cookie: { 
        secure: false,
        httpOnly: true,
        maxAge:keys.session.maxAge, // satu hari,
        sameSite:true,
     }

}));

// app.use('/public',express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(csrf({ cookie: false }));

app.disable('x-powered-by');
app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    res.header('X-XSS-Protection', '1; mode=block');
    res.header('X-Frame-Options','deny');
    res.header('X-Content-Type-Options','nosniff');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");
    res.cookie('csrf_token', req.csrfToken(), { maxAge: 3600, sameSite: true })
    next(); 
})

app.use(cors({ origin: keys.origin.url }))

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {

    var ua = UAparser(req.headers['user-agent']);
    res.end(JSON.stringify(ua, null, '  '));
})
app.use('/api/', ensureSession, [
    CategoryRoutes, 
    ProductRoutes, 
    CartRoutes, 
    AuthRoutes, 
    TrackRoutes, 
    AddressRoutes, 
    ShippingRoutes, 
    UIRoutes,
    LookbookRoutes,
    CheckoutRoutes
]);

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, (err) => {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        console.log(`Server running on port ! ${port}`);
    }

});
```

**From Client using Redux**

```
export const fetchCartList = (value)=>disbatch=>{
    console.log(Cookies.get())
    disbatch(loadingCart());
    axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/api/v1/track/cart',
        headers: { "x-csrf-token": Cookies.get("csrt_token") }
    }).then(res => {
        let dataType = typeof res.data.cart_list;
        if(typeof res.data.token_c !== "undefined"){
            localStorage.setItem("hammerstout_c", res.data.token_c);
        }
        if(dataType !== "undefined"){
        disbatch({
            type:FETCH_CART_LIST,
            payload:res.data.cart_list
        })
        }else{
            disbatch(stopLoadingCart());
            localStorage.removeItem("hammerstout_c");
        }


    }).catch(err => {
        disbatch({
            type: GET_ERRORS,
            payload: err.response.data
        });
        if (err.response.data.error) {
            disbatch(stopLoadingCart());
        }
    })
}
```

**Result**

Sometimes i got error like this :

CSRF is undefined :

[image: CSRF IS UNDEFINED]

in first request i set Cookie :
[image: CSRF SET]

[image: request list]

Sometimes Success :
as you can see CSRF TOKEN HAS BEEN SET :
[image: TOKEN HAS BEEN SET]
[image: CSRF SET SUCCESS]

most of what I find is React server-side rendering instead of client-side rendering.

**So how to secure React Single Page App/Creat React App ?**

please give me an example or tutorial on handling this CSRF using Express and React SPA

I've tried it a few days and the results still don't work :(

Comment: where is your code? what bugs were you seeing? what did you do to try to fix them? what specific problem do you have?

Comment: Wouldn't you want to set the cookie value to true, where you have `app.use(csrf({ cookie: false }));`

Comment: Also the app.use(csrf (..)) needs to be after all bodyParser uses since the body needs to be parsed before the check occurs.

Comment: I have tried changing app.use (csrf ({cookie: true})); and I get a new cookie that is _csrf still doesnt work. @jakobinn

Comment: what do you mean by app.use (csrf (..)) needs to be after all bodyParser ? i just need to check cookie. and actually I have tried changing it and still not working @jakobinn

Comment: `app.use(csrf (...))` should come after all bodyParsing usage, such as `app.use(bodyParser.json());`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188135/discussion-between-farisdev-and-jakobinn).